# What's the difference between the Parity-Ethereum and the Parity client?

Tags: parity, nodes, clients

If you open https://etherscan.io/nodetracker you can see that the second most prevalent Ethereum client is Parity-Ethereum followed by Parity. What is the difference between these two client types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See pull request [9052](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/pull/9052).

This rename was made when Parity's version was bumped from 1.x to 2.0.0. The newer 2.0 clients are therefore `Parity-Ethereum`.